# XML to read get child containing specific value -Java

Tags: java, xmlreader

I'm having trouble to get some particular element, i have an xml file which has root node "problem" which contains children "solutions". In the solutions i have tag name "cost" which has value 505.9208295302417, i want to get all elements in this child containing 505.9208295302417. All that I've done so far is all the nodes i want only this particular child's element not the other. below are the xml and the java code.

```html
      <problem>    
      <solution>
      <cost>505.9214355631349</cost>
                   <routes>
                        <route>
                             <driverId>noDriver</driverId>
                             <vehicleId>1_1</vehicleId>
                             <start>0.0</start>
                             <act type="service">
                                  <serviceId>5 </serviceId>
                                  <arrTime>109.9819741964403</arrTime>
                                  <endTime>119.9819741964403</endTime>
                             </act>
                             <end>229.9639483928806</end>
                        </route>
                        <route>
                             <driverId>noDriver</driverId>
                             <vehicleId>3_1</vehicleId>
                             <start>0.0</start>
                             <act type="service">
                                  <serviceId>2 </serviceId>
                                  <arrTime>109.98268205388193</arrTime>
                                  <endTime>119.98268205388193</endTime>
                             </act>
                             <act type="service">
                                  <serviceId>1 </serviceId>
                                  <arrTime>119.98357684436793</arrTime>
                                  <endTime>129.98357684436792</endTime>
                             </act>
                             <act type="service">
                                  <serviceId>3 </serviceId>
                                  <arrTime>129.98449911991617</arrTime>
                                  <endTime>139.98449911991617</endTime>
                             </act>
                             <act type="service">
                                  <serviceId>4 </serviceId>
                                  <arrTime>139.98539391040217</arrTime>
                                  <endTime>149.98539391040217</endTime>
                             </act>
                             <end>259.9672978232725</end>
                        </route>
                   </routes>
              </solution>
              <solution>
                   <cost>505.9208295302417</cost>
                   <routes>
                        <route>
                             <driverId>noDriver</driverId>
                             <vehicleId>1_1</vehicleId>
                             <start>0.0</start>
                             <act type="service">
                                  <serviceId>5 </serviceId>
                                  <arrTime>109.9819741964403</arrTime>
                                  <endTime>119.9819741964403</endTime>
                             </act>
                             <end>229.9639483928806</end>
                        </route>
                        <route>
                             <driverId>noDriver</driverId>
                             <vehicleId>3_1</vehicleId>
                             <start>0.0</start>
                             <act type="service">
                                  <serviceId>4 </serviceId>
                                  <arrTime>109.98190391287031</arrTime>
                                  <endTime>119.98190391287031</endTime>
                             </act>
                             <act type="service">
                                  <serviceId>2 </serviceId>
                                  <arrTime>119.98282618841856</arrTime>
                                  <endTime>129.98282618841856</endTime>
                             </act>
                             <act type="service">
                                  <serviceId>1 </serviceId>
                                  <arrTime>129.98372097890456</arrTime>
                                  <endTime>139.98372097890456</endTime>
                             </act>
                             <act type="service">
                                  <serviceId>3 </serviceId>
                                  <arrTime>139.9846432544528</arrTime>
                                  <endTime>149.9846432544528</endTime>
                             </act>
                             <end>259.9668316441239</end>
                        </route>
                   </routes>
              </solution>
</problem>
```

```
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        //System.out.println("route : "
                          // + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
        System.out.println("DriverId : "
                           + eElement.getElementsByTagName("driverId")
                             .item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("vehicleId : "
                           + eElement.getElementsByTagName("vehicleId")
                             .item(0).getTextContent());

                NodeList optionList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("act");
    for (int j = 0; j < optionList.getLength(); ++j)
    {
        Element option = (Element) optionList.item(j);
        for(int k =0;k<1;++k){
        String optionText = option.getTextContent();
       address.add(optionText.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]"," "));
        System.out.println("Citizen :"+optionText.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]"," "));}
        ;


    }
             System.out.println("cost : "
                           + eElement.getElementsByTagName("end")
                             .item(0).getTextContent());
    }
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

***UPDATE***Here i manage to get what i want, but there is a prob, for the citizen i have only the first "act" tag i need to get all the tags value

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

/**
 *
 * @author HP
 */
public class JavaApplication39 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int totalVehicle;
            totalVehicle = 2;
            File fXmlFile = new File("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/solution.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            Double requiredCost = 505.9208295302417;
            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            // NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("route");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("solution");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node solutionNode = nodeList.item(i);

                if (solutionNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element solutionElement = (Element) solutionNode;
                    Node costNode = solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("cost").item(0);
                    Node route = solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("routes").item(0);
                    // if correct cost, proceed to parse further
                    Double costValue = Double.valueOf(costNode.getTextContent());
                    if (Double.compare(requiredCost, costValue) == 0) {
                        System.out.println("working");
                        // there you go, found the node with the cost 505.9208295302417
                        // now just parse all the node elements you need here

                        System.out.println("cost : "
                                + solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("cost")
                                        .item(0).getTextContent());
                        for (int h = 0; h < totalVehicle; h++) {
                            System.out.println("DriverId : "
                                    + solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("driverId")
                                            .item(h).getTextContent().toString());
                            System.out.println("vehicleId : "
                                    + solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("vehicleId")
                                            .item(h).getTextContent());

                            System.out.println("citizen: "
                                    + solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("act")
                                            .item(h).getTextContent());


                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println(address.get(1)); 
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question - are you saying you want to get all the **child nodes** of the `solution` node that contains the `<cost>505.9208295302417</cost>` element?

Comment: You might just want to use xslt to extract it. Or if you need to create a Java object from it, consider creating a model object with JAXB annotations which will fill from the file automatically.

Comment: @MattJones there are 2 child nodes solution right? one of the solution contains element <cost>505.9208295302417</cost>, i want to get all the element in the solution which contains <cost>505.9208295302417</cost>

Comment: @jaxb would take additional time to understand :( i don't have time :(

Comment: the code above gave me all the elements in both children(solution), I only need elements in the solution which contains <cost>505.9208295302417</cost>

Comment: elements needed {driverid,vehicleid,citizen and cost}

Comment: any help? @MattJones

Comment: @daniu any help?

Comment: Do you have an xsd for that file?

Comment: @daniu i turned myself in Xpath in order to get the values , but now i'm stuck with a nullpointer exception see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063775/nullpointer-iterate-through-xml take a look please :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it just me or I don't see any comparison in your code? Checking if node has the cost you need? You can just loop through solution nodes (as you are doing) and once correct cost value found, parse all the elements you need from that node.

Example code:

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("solution");
Double requiredCost = 505.9208295302417;
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

    Node solutionNode = nodeList.item(i);

    if (solutionNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element solutionElement = (Element) solutionNode;
        Node costNode = solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("cost").item(0);

        // if correct cost, proceed to parse further
        Double costValue = Double.valueOf(costNode.getTextContent());
        if (Double.compare(requiredCost, costValue) == 0) {

            // there you go, found the node with the cost 505.9208295302417
            // now just parse all the node elements you need here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey sorry to disturb  again :( it is giving me wrong output , i must be messing with something, i tried to change            Node costNode = solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("cost").item(0);)           to       Node costNode = solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("routes").item(0);) it gave me the correct anwer but outlined in red with some conversion error

Comment: I'm confused :(

Comment: in the if statement what code i need to write in order to get vehicleid for example ? i tried to put the my codes still not giving the right ids

Comment: help please i'm desperate :(

Comment: @MattieuKevin What do you mean it gives you the wrong output? What do you get? This code gets you the node with cose value `505.9208295302417` just as you asked...All you have to do is get `Element solutionElement` children. Put some effort atleast, don't just copy paste blindly.

Comment: It gave me vehicle id 1_1 , it sould be giving me 1_1 and 1_3

Comment: @MattieuKevin Post your code that gave you this output.

Comment: I've post the code, the prob that im having is that it is only gving me the first "act" tag value i need to get all the tags, see if you could help me please

Comment: Any help ?? Its been 4 days that im dealing with this code :( im going to fail my exam for sure

Comment: @MattieuKevin You retrieve only the first route node, `Node route = solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("routes").item(0);`. Don't use hardcoded values to loop, `totalVehicle`. Loop through node children. `routes->loop through children; route->loop through children`

Comment: i haven't use use solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("routes").item(0); at all, the code that you provided is woking fine the only prob that im facing is with  getting all the act values which corresponds to the routes see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105563/how-to-loop-in-each-node-java-xml

Comment: @MattieuKevin That's because you ignore parent/child note relationship and get all act nodes from solution node. When looping through route nodes, get act nodes from ROUTE node. Since act nodes belong to route node.

Comment: @MattieuKevin You really should avoid things like `totalVehicle` in your loops. What would happen if a 3rd route nodes was added?

Comment: i'm getting lost, so you are telling me to redefine a nodelist(route) and then loop through it ?

Comment: totalvehicle is user defined , and xml file is dynamic according to the total vehicles